# Regex for range 0.01-100000 JS

Tags: javascript, regex

How to create regEx from getting result is number in range from 0.01 to 1 000 000
Thanks

Comment: Why does it have to be a regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you wouldn't want a regular expression for that.

Instead you can simply test your number like `n >= 0.01 && n <= 100000`.

Comment: Not necessarily true. There are contexts where you can provide a regex for filtering, but not arbitrary code.

Comment: I have seen such contexts indeed, but not in javascript. Do you have an example?